# entry.description; not working with jGFeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jGFeed to parse an RSS Feed, my code for which is below:

```
$.jGFeed('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml',
          function(feeds){
            // Check for errors
            if(!feeds){
              // there was an error
              return false;
            }
            // do whatever you want with feeds here
            $('#newsTimeline').empty();
            for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
                var entry = feeds.entries[i];
                var title = entry.title;
                var description = entry.description;
                var linkUrl = entry.link_url;
                var date = getDate(entry.pubDate);
                var time = getTime(entry.pubDate);
                $('#newsTimeline').append('<li><time class="cbp_tmtime" datetime="'+date+' '+time+'"><span>'+date+'</span> <span>'+time+'</span></time><div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-phone"></div><div class="cbp_tmlabel"><h2>'+title+'</h2><p>'+description+'</p></div></li>');
            }
        }, 10);
```

The problem is that it is working for entry.title, but nothing after that works:
[image: The final page]

---

**NOTE: No errors are logged in the Javascript Console.**

Comment: how does the array look? can you post a sample?

Comment: @Omar Here is a screenshot http://blog.bobcravens.com/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/BuildanRSSFeedReaderwithjQueryandjGFeed_13A47/image_4.png

Comment: i cant see description, pls post one array/object at least.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
       for(var i=0;i<feeds.entries.length;i++){
            var entry = feeds.entries[i];
            var title = entry.title;
            var linkUrl= entry.link;
            var description = entry.contentSnippet;
            var date = entry.publishedDate;
            $('#newsTimeline').append('<li><time class="cbp_tmtime" datetime="'+date+'       '+time+'"><span>'+date+'</span> <span>'+time+'</span></time><div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-phone"></div><div class="cbp_tmlabel"><h2>'+title+'</h2><p>'+description+'</p></div></li>');
            }
```